# XSLT condition to check if node exists

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I have below sample XML in which I want to check if the node  exist.

Sample XML is

```
<document>
<item>
    <ID>1000909090</ID>
    <flex>
        <attrGroupMany name="pageinfo">
            <row>
                <attr name="pagelength">10</attr>
                <attr name="pagewidth">20</attr>
                <attr name="pageheight">30</attr>
            </row>
            <row>
                <attr name="pagelength">10</attr>
                <attr name="pagewidth">20</attr>
            </row>
        </attrGroupMany>
    </flex>
</item>
</document>
```

I am using below XSLT but is not getting converted

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="document">
    <CatalogItem>
        <RelationshipData>
            <xsl:for-each select="item">
                <Relationship>
                    <RelationType>PAGEDETAILSINFO</RelationType>
                    <RelatedItems>
                        <xsl:attribute name="count">
                            <xsl:value-of select="count(flex//attrGroupMany[@name = 'pageinfo']/row)"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:for-each select="flex//attrGroupMany[@name = 'pageinfo']/row">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="not(string-length(attr[@name = 'pageheight'] )) = 0">
                                    <xsl:variable name="height" select="attr[@name='pageheight']"/>
                                </xsl:when>                                                         
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:variable name="height" select="'0'"/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose> 
                            <RelatedItem>
                                <xsl:attribute name="referenceKey">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Food_And_Bev_Allergen_MVL','-',ancestor::item/ID,'-',$height)"/>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                            </RelatedItem>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </RelatedItems>
                </Relationship>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </RelationshipData>
    </CatalogItem>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think the choose condition is incorrect. can you please let me know what will be the correct condition.

Comment: Could you post the output you are looking for?

Comment: I've rolled back the OP's edit - the original question was edited to present a second issue with the transform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to adjust the default logic as Stuart suggests, but the main problem is that **the `height` variable scope must be corrected**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="document">
    <CatalogItem>
      <RelationshipData>
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
          <Relationship>
            <RelationType>PAGEDETAILSINFO</RelationType>
            <RelatedItems>
              <xsl:attribute name="count">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(flex//attrGroupMany[@name = 'pageinfo']/row)"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:for-each select="flex//attrGroupMany[@name = 'pageinfo']/row">
                <xsl:variable name="height">
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not(attr[@name = 'pageheight'])">                                       
                      <xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
                    </xsl:when>                                                         
                    <xsl:otherwise>                                     
                      <xsl:value-of select="attr[@name='pageheight']"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <RelatedItem>
                  <xsl:attribute name="referenceKey">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Food_And_Bev_Allergen_MVL','-',ancestor::item/ID,'-',$height)"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                </RelatedItem>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </RelatedItems>
          </Relationship>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </RelationshipData>
    </CatalogItem>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**After making the above changes, this input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
  <item>
    <ID>1000909090</ID>
    <flex>
      <attrGroupMany name="pageinfo">
        <row>
          <attr name="pagelength">10</attr>
          <attr name="pagewidth">20</attr>
          <attr name="pageheight">30</attr>
        </row>
        <row>
          <attr name="pagelength">10</attr>
          <attr name="pagewidth">20</attr>
        </row>
      </attrGroupMany>
    </flex>
  </item>
</document>
```

**Will transform to this output XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CatalogItem>
   <RelationshipData>
      <Relationship>
         <RelationType>PAGEDETAILSINFO</RelationType>
         <RelatedItems count="2">
            <RelatedItem referenceKey="Food_And_Bev_Allergen_MVL-1000909090-30"/>
            <RelatedItem referenceKey="Food_And_Bev_Allergen_MVL-1000909090-0"/>
         </RelatedItems>
      </Relationship>
   </RelationshipData>
</CatalogItem>
```

### Edit

**Note that the following is a more natural expression of the default logic:**

```
            <xsl:variable name="height">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="attr[@name = 'pageheight']">
                  <xsl:value-of select="attr[@name='pageheight']"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
```

### Edit 2

**Or, if you're using XSLT 2.0, you can use the sequence idiom for default values very concisely:**

```
            <xsl:variable name="height" 
                          select="(attr[@name='pageheight'], 0)[1]"/>
```

Comment: I had another issue with finding duplicate. can you please help in that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600753/removal-of-duplicates-from-xslt-nodes

Comment: @user3852047 I think you have been told already what's wrong with that other question, you did not bother to write code in the first place, that's the problem. By the way, +1 of course, Kenneth.

Answer (score 3):

To determine whether the attribute is present or not, simply use `not()` when the element is current.

I would reverse the logic, viz move the `not present` first:

```
<xsl:when test="not(attr[@name='pageheight'])">
  ... not present, default it
```

Will detect if the row has no `attr` elements with a `@name attribute`.

**Edit**

You can't assign `<xsl:variable>` in a branch like that - it will go out of scope within the `xsl:choose`. Switch to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="document">
    <CatalogItem>
      <RelationshipData>
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
          <Relationship>
            <RelationType>PAGEDETAILSINFO</RelationType>
            <RelatedItems>
              <xsl:attribute name="count">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(flex//attrGroupMany[@name = 'pageinfo']/row)"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:for-each select="flex//attrGroupMany[@name = 'pageinfo']/row">
                <xsl:variable name="height">
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not(attr[@name = 'pageheight'])">
                      <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:value-of select="attr[@name='pageheight']"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <RelatedItem>
                  <xsl:attribute name="referenceKey">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Food_And_Bev_Allergen_MVL','-',ancestor::item/ID,'-',$height)"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                </RelatedItem>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </RelatedItems>
          </Relationship>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </RelationshipData>
    </CatalogItem>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the returned snippet includes:

```
  <RelatedItems count="2">
    <RelatedItem referenceKey="Food_And_Bev_Allergen_MVL-1000909090-30" />
    <RelatedItem referenceKey="Food_And_Bev_Allergen_MVL-1000909090-0" />
  </RelatedItems>
```

Comment: I did but still i am not able to convert. I have updated the XSLT which i tried, not sure where I am going wrong

Comment: I had another issue with finding duplicate. can you please help in that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600753/removal-of-duplicates-from-xslt-nodes

Comment: @user3852047 Please [**accept this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem. - And please do the same for all your older questions where valid answer have been provided, but you did not accept any of them.

Comment: Right, Stuart provided a clear explanation of your problem (+1) (a few minutes before I did).  Please accept his answer rather than ask him to consider your other question, where at least 9 readers have directed you appropriately to review an apropos reference and make progress rather than asking for code to be written for you.  Thank you.